# Insert plot into mysql from Mathematica as blob

Tags: mysql, wolfram-mathematica

In php you can insert pictures into database as blob data type. I'd like to put plots of data into a database as a blob datatype so I can reuse this data on the web with php. 
For example:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
conn=OpenSQLConnection["myDB"];
picture=Plot[Sin[x], {x,0,2Pi}];
SQLExecute[conn, "INSERT INTO pictures VALUES ('"<>picture<>"')"]
```

Comment: Would Exporting to a file and then loading into the database do? [this list of possible export formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ExportFormats.html)might include something suitable.

Comment: Do you know about `ExportString`? You can create the file-content of an image with this an use it to insert it into your DB. `img = Image[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]; ExportString[img, "PNG"]`

Comment: What I have done in the past for database applications is save the image to a directory and reference it in the DB rather than store it there. If you want to use images in a web application you can still do that using this method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an example in V 8.0.4 documentation page `SQLBinary` that gives the steps needed. After you export `picture` to a format of your choice as @halirutan and @Verbeia suggested, say

```
img=ExportString[picture, "PNG"];
```

you need to convert the resulting string to raw binary data using

```
byteData=SQLBinary[ToCharacterCode[img]];
```

Assuming the column `pictures` (with datatype `LONGVARBINARY, VARBINARY` or `BINARY`) lives in, say, `PICTABLE` then insert `byteData` into the `pictures` column using

```
SQLInsert[conn, "PICTABLE", {"pictures"}, {byteData}];
```

or equivalent raw SQL command inside `SQLExecute[ ... ]`.